# Character compared to a digit

Tags: c, io

I am very new to programming, specifically C. I was trying to do a hide/mask a password as an excercise. Made this code to but I was not able to input a `\n` character.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
   char pasword[10], ch;
   int i;

   while(i<=9 )
   {
      ch=getch();
      if((ch >= 'a' && ch<='z') || (ch>='A' && ch<='Z'))
      {
        pasword[i] = ch;
        i++;
        printf("*");
      }
   }

   pasword[i] = '\0';

   printf("Password: %s", pasword);
   return 0;
   }
```

So I tried to search around different forums, found a snippet of code and added it to my if statement.

```
/* some code at the top */
}else if(ch == 13){
    break;
}
```

It somehow made me allow to input a `\n` or 'Enter'. 

Why is `ch` compared to `13`? Or what is `13` in this sense? Why is it that when I change `13` to another number I couldn't press Enter?

May I also add that why couldn't I erase the text I have typed?

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: You forgot to initialize your `i` variable.

Comment: Get a better compiler asap. You should get a warning for using non-initialized variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this code is with its own faults to be dealt with.

You need to initialize `i` to a valid value, mostly the `0`.
Then your `while` loop would be guaranteed to get executed.

```
while(i <= 9)
```

Additionally, since your are adding a `'\0'` in the last-used index, your loop should execute at the most 9 times. So, `while(i <= 9)` should be changed to `while(i < 9)` so that it gets executed 9 times instead of 10.

Now, to answer your real question, `13` (`0x0D` in Hexadecimal) is called Carriage Return. Refer any (correct) ASCII table such as [this one here](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html).

The wikipedia says,

> A carriage return, sometimes known as a cartridge return and often shortened to CR,  or return, is a control character or mechanism used to reset a device's position to the beginning of a line of text. It is closely associated with the line feed and newline concepts, although it can be considered separately in its own right.

With further reference from the same,

> In computing, the carriage return is one of the control characters in ASCII code, Unicode, EBCDIC, and many other codes. It commands a printer, or other output system such as the display of a system console, to move the position of the cursor to the first position on the same line. It was mostly used along with line feed (LF), a move to the next line, so that together they start a new line. Together, this sequence can be referred to as CRLF.

And,

> Many computer programs use the carriage return character, alone or with a line feed, to signal the end of a line of text.

Reading at the last cited text, you could possibly imagine why any of user input programs proceed from `scanf` after user presses an ENTER key. Thats the usual case when it is treated as a 'End of line'.

So when,

```
if((ch >= 'a' && ch<='z') || (ch>='A' && ch<='Z'))
{

}
else if(ch == 13) //This has allowed you to check if the user has pressed Enter on keyboard.
{
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. May I also ask why I am unable to erase any of my typed text in the console? Or do I have to make a new thread for it?

Comment: @AAngelo Don't mix questions in the same question. If you have another issue raise another question.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I understand sir. Sorry

Comment: @AAngelo: Happy learning! 'Sir' is not by StackExchange standards, or the way people contribute here. Avoid it henceforth. Thank you.